# Basics of Vectors (bearings)

Tags: vectors

I have no idea where I am going wrong with this question: [image]

This is my working out, so you guys would know what was going through my head
[image]

Comment: I assume the question is "what is the distance $AC$?" $\angle ABC=110^\circ$ not $120^\circ$, but you used the correct value in your calculation and got the correct answer. I assume the answer of 1150 is just rounding to the nearest 10.

Comment: Yeah, you are meant to find the distance from A to C. I accidentally wrote 120 degrees for that, but yes I still got 1152.536m as my answer. And the question does not say to round it to the nearest 10, in fact it doesn't say anything about rounding the value.